# Absolute position images in a relative div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-position

I want to make a responsive design with different images, for example:

```
 <div id="home" class="page"> 
    <div id="home_1" class="section"><!-- Page 1 -->
        <div id="home_1_1" class="full">
            <img src="images/home/home_1/home_1.png" class="full-image"></img>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="home_2" class="section"><!-- Page 2 -->
        <div id="home_2_1" class="full">
            <img src="images/home/home_2/home_2_block1.png" class="full-image"></img>
        </div>
        <div id="home_2_2" class="full">
             <img src="images/home/home_2/home_2_block2.png" class="full-image"></img>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="home_3" class="section"><!-- Page 3 -->
        <div id="home_3_1" class="full">
            <img src="images/home/home_3/home_3_block1.png" class="full-image"></img>
        </div>
        <div id="home_3_2" class="full">
            <img src="images/home/home_3/home_3_block2.png" class="full-image"></img>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`home_1`, `home_2` and `home_3` are seperate image blocks. but `home_2_1` `home_2_2` should have the same top position and they also should be below `home_1`.

this is my css:

```
#home{
    width: 100%;
    text-wrap: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.section{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.full{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
.full-image{
   width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

The problem is that I see only one image, the others don't floats beside each other.
I hope somebody can help me with this.

Comment: to get a responsible design, you have to be a responsible designer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you mean, but have you tried just using floats?

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9Ryby/

```
.section {
    clear: both;
}
.full-image {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not what i wan't, sorry for my bad description, i  wan't the images for example in home_2 and home_3 one above the other.